# lazily activate an ELPA package?

Tags: package, start-up, autoload

I'd like a way to lazily activate certain ~/.emacs.d/elpa packages. I notice some of them have so many autoloads (which require other packages recursively from their `*-autoloads.el`), that you might as well just `(require 'them)`.

Can I, for example, activate all *except* certain packages? I see you can set `package-load-list` to `(all)` or a list of names and versions, but I can't see anything like `(all-but ,(alist))` in the docs.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to report that as a bug to the relevant package(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I, for example, activate all *except* certain packages? I see you can set `package-load-list` to `(all)` or a list of names and versions, but I can't see anything like `(all-but ,(alist))` in the docs.

You should be able to use `((a-slow-package . nil) (an-even-slower-package . nil) all)`.

As described in the docstring:

```
Each element in this list should be a list (NAME VERSION), or the
symbol ‘all’.  The symbol ‘all’ says to load the latest installed
versions of all packages not specified by other elements.

For an element (NAME VERSION), NAME is a package name (a symbol).
[...]
If VERSION is nil, the package is not loaded (it is "disabled").
```

Comment: Nice, I can now do `(let ((package-load-list '((a-slow-package . nil) (an-even-slower-package . nil) all))) (package-initialize))` in my init.el, along with something like `(use-package :if (package-installed-p 'a-slow-package) :init (defun my-start-slowness () (interactive) (package-activate 'a-slow-package) (a-slow-package-mode)))` for requiring it when needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult with `package.el` because `package.el` is not designed for modular package management. I suggest you use a different package manager, such as [`straight.el`](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el) (which I wrote in order to solve the problems of `package.el`).

With `straight.el`, conditionally loading a package is trivial: just conditionally load it:

```
(when some-condition
  (straight-use-package 'my-slow-package))
```

This works because (unlike `package.el`), `straight.el` does exactly what you ask it to, and nothing more. Thus, preventing `straight.el` from installing and loading a package is as simple as not asking it to do so.

You can read verbose documentation about `straight.el`, including comparisons to other package managers, in the [README](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el).

#### Footnote for advanced `straight.el` users

If you use [version lockfiles](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el#lockfile-management), then you want to be sure that the revisions of all your packages are recorded in your lockfile, even if they are not currently being loaded. This can be accomplished via

```
(if some-condition
    (straight-use-package 'my-slow-package)
  (straight-register-package 'my-slow-package))
```

although a more convenient syntax using [`use-package`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) is planned in [this issue](https://github.com/raxod502/straight.el/issues/45).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
(package-initialize 'no-activate)
(let* ((no-activate '(a-slow-package an-even-slower-package)))
    (mapc (lambda (s) (unless (member s no-activate)
                (package-activate s)))
          (mapcar #'car package-alist)))
```